# Ploting a histogram in ggplot in the right way

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
score <- c(0,0,0,1,2,3,-2,-1)
df <- data.frame(score)
```

Now I would like to plot an histogram using 
the ggplot function:

```
g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = score))
g + geom_histogram(breaks = seq(-3,3,by=1), col = "red", fill = "green", alpha = .2) + labs(x="Age", y="Count")
```

It works and looks fine but I wonder if the axes are labelled correctly? I also get the feeling the histogram is slighly negative. Actually I would like to plot it so it the 0 bin is centred between -0.5 an +0.5.

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Comment: Why don't you just do this breaks = seq(-2.5,2.5,by=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the breaks argument and set binwidth to 1.

`g + geom_histogram(col = "red", fill = "green", alpha = .2,binwidth = 1) + labs(x="Age", y="Count")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the histogram 'balanced' by showing the the bar for each value within the -3:3 range, you can also try this. It calculates the frequency for each value using `table` then adds a dummy for -3 with frequency 0.

```
score <- c(0,0,0,1,2,3,-2,-1)
df <- data.frame(score)

df2 <- data.frame(table(df))
df2 <- rbind(data.frame(df = "-3", Freq = 0), df2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = df, y = Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", col = "red", fill = "green", alpha = .2) +
  labs(x="Age", y="Count")
```

[image]